# File Upload Error using php

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload, upload

I have written some code to upload a file in MySQL database using php.
Following is my code to upload file.

```
$data['report_type']     = $this->input->post('report_type');
        $data['document_type']   = $this->input->post('document_type');
        $data['prescription_id'] = $this->input->post('prescription_id');
        $data['description']     = $this->input->post('description');
        $data['timestamp']       = strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . ' ' . date('H:i:s'));
        $data['laboratorist_id'] = $this->session->userdata('laboratorist_id');
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/diagnosis_report/" . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
        $data['file_name'] = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];

        $this->db->insert('diagnosis_report', $data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('diagnosis_report_created'));
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?laboratorist/manage_prescription/edit/' . $this->input->post('prescription_id'), 'refresh');
```

Whenever I try to upload any file. It Gives an error as

> Column 'file_name' cannot be null
>
> INSERT INTO `diagnosis_report` (`report_type`, `document_type`, `prescription_id`, `description`, `timestamp`, `laboratorist_id`, `file_name`) VALUES (0, 0, 0, 0, 1392206996, '1', NULL)

Whats wrong with my code ?

Comment: `INSERT INTO diagnosis_report (report_type, document_type, prescription_id, description, timestamp, laboratorist_id, file_name) VALUES (0, 0, 0, 0, 1392206996, '1', '')`

Comment: are you using codeigniter framework

Comment: yes @Jenz ! I'm using Codeigniter framework !

Answer (score 0):

The SQL error:

> Column 'file_name' cannot be null

refers to your last column on the insert statement. You're attempting to set it to `NULL` when the `file_name` column has `NOT NULL` in it's column definition.

Two solutions:

One, run an alter table command on your database table to allow `NULL` values.

```
ALTER TABLE diagnosis_report MODIFY COLUMN file_name [datatype] DEFAULT NULL [etc]
```

Generally not recommended if it's part of a CMS, or package you don't maintain. If it's standalone code, this solution is usable.

Or two, modify your PHP to not set `file_name` to `NULL`, but just an empty string:

```
INSERT INTO diagnosis_report (report_type, document_type, prescription_id, description, timestamp, laboratorist_id, file_name) VALUES (0, 0, 0, 0, 1392206996, '1', '')
```

Comment: I tried your code but Its just showing that file successfully uploaded but not actually storing in db.

Comment: Can you confirm the file is getting saved `using move_uploaded_file`? If this is not the case, you may want to do a little debugging to check if the files exist in `$_FILES`. If not, it could be a form or server issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data['file_name']
```

is returning NULL value because user uploaded files are stored inside the `$_FILES` variable and not in `$_POST`.

Use the codeigniter's upload library:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: I made it as following -               move_uploaded_file($_POST["userfile"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/diagnosis_report/" . $_POST["userfile"]["name"]);
                                                                $data['file_name'] = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
                                                       but still cant store file

Answer (score 0):

From your attached code segment erase these two lines:-

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/diagnosis_report/" . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
$data['file_name'] = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
```

Instead of above two lines, add below code lines -

```
$move='/uploads/diagnosis_report/';
$uploadfile=$_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
$path=$move.basename($uploadfile);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], SITE_ROOT.$path);
$data['file_name'] = basename($uploadfile);
```

Now you have to do one more thing
go to **\application\views\laboratorist**. Open **manage_prescription.php** , there you will get below code segment

```
<!------ADD A DIAGNOSTIC REPORT TO THIS PRESCRIPTION-->
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="box-header"><span class="title"><?php echo get_phrase('add_diagnosis_report');?></span></div>
                        <div class="box-content">
                        <?php echo form_open('laboratorist/manage_prescription/create_diagnosis_report' , array('class' => 'form-horizontal validatable'));?>
```

Now change that respective **form_open** to **form_open_multipart**

```
 <!------ADD A DIAGNOSTIC REPORT TO THIS PRESCRIPTION-->
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="box-header"><span class="title"><?php echo get_phrase('add_diagnosis_report');?></span></div>
                        <div class="box-content">
                        <?php echo form_open_multipart('laboratorist/manage_prescription/create_diagnosis_report' , array('class' => 'form-horizontal validatable'));?>

               I hope now it will run successfully. Please let me know if it doesn't work. Thanks.
```